# MPandroidChart Layout Height

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the MPAndroidChart to create a bar chart inside a fragment, but the chart height is only a fraction of the total screen. Also, when the height is set to a number, it works properly, but that is not the solution that I want. What is the problem? 
Here is the fragment layout code below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
            android:id="@+id/barchart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of details, I used the Tabbed Activity with Action Bar Spinner template for my project.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Also I have the image of the application running

[Click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aHaz.png)

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? You've set the height of your `RelativeLayout` to `wrap_content`, so presumably there are other Views above or below your `RelativeLayout` that are also taking up room.

Comment: I already tried "match_parent" and "fill_parent" and the results are the same, also I didn't add any other views

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question, but I ran into the same problem - my programmatically created chart was wide as needed, but the height wasn't being inherited from the parent linearLayout.
The solution involved setting the height programmatically after adding it to the view of the parent, then redrawing it (invalidate()).

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/short_performance_chart"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/graph_gradient"/>
```

Code:

```
LinearLayout chartHolder = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.short_performance_chart);
BarChart mChart = (BarChart) initializeBarChart(); //just populating data, etc
chartHolder.addView(mChart);
// Due to the fact that we are in a fragment we have to reset the height
mChart.getLayoutParams().height = android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
mChart.invalidate();
```

Comment: Does not work for me.  At square one and I already can't get a single chart to render correctly.  Not a good sign.

Comment: do you invalidate the chart (draw the chart) during initializeBarChart() ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap chart with a `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_lineChartImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    >
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/lineChartImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then chage the size of the `FrameLayout` dynamically

```
val imageChart: LineChart =findViewById(R.id.lineChartImage)
fl_imageChart: FrameLayout =findViewById(R.id.fl_lineChartImage)
val params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = fl_imageChart.getLayoutParams()
params.width = FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
params.height = 100  //enter size here
fl_imageChart.setLayoutParams(params)
imageChart.invalidate()
```